# Disable Bash completion for a single environmental variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, variable, autocomplete

Suppose I have an environmental variable `$SAVE_DIR=/etc/` used to return to a saved directory (here `/etc/`) from any Bash shell. Typing `cd $SAV[Tab]` expands to `cd $SAVE_DIR` which is quite convenient. However, later on a second, similarly named `$SAVE_FILE` is introduced, meaning `cd $SAV[Tab]` no longer has a unique completion and Bash lists the two possible variables instead of automatically expanding to the one I want.

My question is whether it is possible to selectively hide the second variable `$SAVE_FILE` from the completion mechanism without renaming it (e.g. because it is needed with this name by an external program), so that I can once again expand `$SAV` to `$SAVE_DIR` in a single `[Tab]` keystroke.

Comment: your $SAVE_DIR variable may not be the best way of doing this.  have you considered using a function, or the `pushd`, `popd`, and `dirs` bash built-ins?   run `help pushd popd dirs | less` in bash for details on them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would like `$SAVE_DIR` to be a persistent location I can refer to in scripts and so on, so I don't think using the directory stack is appropriate. Moreover, it would be nice to know whether blacklisting variable names from auto-completion was possible in general (not just for paths).

Comment: As for a function/alias: I could alias `cds` to `cd $SAVE_DIR`. But what if I want to copy a file to `$SAVE_DIR`? I would need another alias for `cp` (and `rm`, `ls`, etc.).

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible, or at least not easy, but why not just use different variable names and avoid the issue? Call one `SAVE_DIR` and call another `save_dir` or `asodjhasd` or anything else that doesn't trigger autocompletion.

Comment: Thanks, I am mainly wanting to find out whether it is possible (e.g. using `complete` somehow). Renaming should work in most cases apart from maybe if the variable (name and value) is set by an external program, but in that case I could define my own variable with a name that didn't clash that had the same value as `$SAVE_DIR`